# What methods can be implemented: select static library files linked to CGO according to the version of the operating system

Tags: go, cgo

I need to use CGO to link static library files (libcodec.a)

```
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./
#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -L. -lcodec -lstdc++ -ldl -lm
```

But I need to decide which static library file to link according to the operating system version of the deployment server. For example, macOS, centos7, centos8 etc.

My idea is to write a series of  *.go files. Each file links to a static library file corresponding to an operating system. But this method is too cumbersome. Is there a better and more elegant method?

Go version 1.17

Comment: You do not _have to_ set `LDFLAGS` and other similar environment variables known to C toolchains in the `#cgo` directives; it's fine to set them, say, in the `Makefile` (or other configuration of your build system of choice). The downside is that you'd need to use a buildsystem other than `go` itself.

Comment: Maybe `pkg-config` could help as well: basically you call it to obtain proper `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` for a particular system and the libraries it supports.

Comment: Yes, this is why `pkg-config` is used by default.

Comment: Hello, I'm not familiar with pkg-config. Can you give an example of how pkg-config selects compilation parameters according to different operating system versions and cpu architectures? thank you.   @kostix